# RegEx matching for a filename

Tags: c#, regex

I have no experience using regular expressions, and although I should spend some time training in them, I have a need for a simple one.

I want to find a match of P*.txt in a given string (meaning anything that starts with a P, followed by anything, and ending in ".txt".

eg:

```
string myString = "P671221.txt";
Regex reg = new Regex("P*.txt"); //<--- what goes here?

if (reg.IsMatch(myString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Match!"));
    }
```

This example doesn't work because it will return a match for ".txt" or "x.txt" etc. How do I do this?

Comment: `\bP[\d]*.txt\b` this will work. If you have fix number of digits then you can do it like `\bP[\d]{6}.txt\b`. Just replace the 6 with your desired fix number.

Comment: If it's that simple, you can probably just use String.StartsWith and String.EndsWith

Comment: this website helped me learn regex in about an hour, i highly suggest you try it: http://regexr.com/

Comment: The `"P*.txt"` is a wildcard expression, which, while looking similar to a regex, is different from (and much less powerful than) a regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
myString.StartsWith("P") && myString.EndsWith(".txt")
```

EDIT: Removed my regex

Comment: Your regex would match `P toto ztxt`

Comment: While not the best regular expression the suggestion to use `StartsWith` and `EndsWith` are spot on.

Comment: @Thomas Updated to escape dot. OP says filename, so I guess spaces are allowed

Answer (score 1):

## Updated:

string start + (**p**) + **any characters** + **.txt** + string end
`^(?i:p).*\.txt$`

A more precise alternative would be:
string start + (**p**) + [**specific characters**] + **.txt** + string end
( currently specified are: "a-z", "0-9", space, & underscore )
`^(?i:p)(?i:[a-z0-9 _])*\.txt$`

## [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aL7yX1/1)

[image: UpdatedSolution]

---

> #### Original Solution
>
> ( quotes were included, as I overlooked that quotes are part of the code but not
>   the string )
>
> preceding quotes + (**p**) + **any characters** + **.txt** + following quotes
>
> `(?<=")(?i:p).*\.txt(?=")`
>
> **[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxOLW.png)**
>
> **[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gF9fA3/1)**

Comment: The `"` character isn't part of the input.

Answer (score 0):

The best option to get files that start with P & end with .txt *with regex* is:

```
^P\w+\.txt$
```

Comment: Why the restriction to `\w`? And won't this match files that don't start with `P` or end with `.txt` because it's not anchored?

Comment: @Rawling because I come from a place where filename are written just with `\w`. You're right for the anchors

Answer (score 0):

`P[\d]+\.txt` this will work. If you have fix number of digits then you can do it like `P[\d]{6}\.txt`. Just replace the 6 with your desired fix number.

If the value in between the starting letter `P` and extension `.txt` can be alphanumeric use `P[\w]+\.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
string myString = "P671221.txt";
Regex reg = new Regex("P(.*?)\\.txt"); //--> if anything goes after P
if (reg.IsMatch(myString))
    Console.WriteLine("Match!");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should meet the requirements that you have presented.

**c#**

[Pp].*.(?:txt)+$